# CSV Column Counts via Command Line Alias

Tags: bash, ubuntu, csv, scripting, command-line-interface

I have a Bash scripting question that's no longer important to me but has still been driving me crazy because I can't figure it out.

I was trying to compare column counts of CSV files via the command line, and found some instructions [here](http://blog.jarrodswart.com/posts/print-csv-column-count-with-awk/) that looked promising.  The original command worked perfectly, but every attempt to create an alias failed.

Original command line - WORKS!

**head -n 1 FILENAME.CSV | awk '{split($0, pieces, ","); for (i=1; i<=length(pieces); i++) print pieces[i];}' | wc -l**

Ex. molsen@molsen-M14xR2:~/projects/ee-export$ head -n 1 ee-content.csv | awk '{split($0, pieces, ","); for (i=1; i<=length(pieces); i++) print pieces[i];}' | wc -l

7

Aliased command line - FAILS!

**alias csvcc="head -n 1 $1 | awk '{split($0, pieces, ","); for (i=1; i<=length(pieces); i++) print pieces[i];}' | wc -l"**

Ex. molsen@molsen-M14xR2:~/projects/ee-export$ csvcc ee-content.csv

awk: cmd. line:1: {split(bash, pieces, ,); for (i=1; i<=length(pieces); i++) print pieces[i];}

awk: cmd. line:1:                      ^ syntax error

awk: cmd. line:1: {split(bash, pieces, ,); for (i=1; i<=length(pieces); i++) print pieces[i];}

awk: cmd. line:1:                       ^ syntax error

awk: cmd. line:1: {split(bash, pieces, ,); for (i=1; i<=length(pieces); i++) print pieces[i];}

awk: cmd. line:1:                       ^ 0 is invalid as number of arguments for split
1023 ee-content.csv

I've tried all sorts of variations on this command with different quoting and escaping, but they all produce errors.  I even looked into [strong vs. weak quoting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting), but didn't find anything useful.  Also, I came up with this simpler command, but it fails in the same way:

COMMAND LINE USING SED - WORKS!

**head -n 1 file.csv | sed 's/\,/\n/g' | wc -l**

molsen@molsen-M14xR2:~/projects/ee-export$ head -n 1 ee-content.csv | sed 's/\,/\n/g' | wc -l

7

ALIAS USING SED - FAILS (COUNTS LINES, NOT COLUMNS)

**alias csvcc="head -n 1 $1 | sed 's/\,/\n/g' | wc -l"**

molsen@molsen-M14xR2:~/projects/ee-export$ csvcc ee-content.csv

1023 ee-content.csv

Can anyone can tell me what I'm missing here?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rzymek's Solution 1 doesn't work because `csvcc <ee-content.csv` expands to

```
head -n 1 | sed 's/\,/\n/g' | wc -l <ee-content.csv
```

i. e., the input file is not fed to `head`, but to `wc -l`; this explains why it gives the line count.

Another solution with alias and awk:

```
 alias csvcc="awk -F, 'NR==1 { print NF }'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Aliases don't use `$1`, scripts do.

**Solution 1.**

```
alias csvcc="head -n 1  | sed 's/\,/\n/g' | wc -l"
                       ^--- no $1, input will be read from stdin
```

Usage:

```
csvcs < ee-content.csv
```

**Solution 2.**

Put the line in a bash script file in `$HOME/bin/csvcc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
head -n 1  | sed 's/\,/\n/g' | wc -l
```

Then make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/csvcc
```

On ubuntu `$HOME/bin` is added to `$PATH` by default. If it's not on your system, than add this line to your `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Usage:

```
csvcs ee-content.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, but the alias still gives the row count, not the column count.  Any idea why?